# javascript: добавление элементов в массив по условию

Tags: javascript, массивы

подскажите, как можно поэлегантнее, без кучи строчек кода с `if` реализовать следующую задачу:

есть массив `arr`, есть 2 элемента `value1` и `value2`, которые надо добавить в начало массива, если эти элементы определены (не равны `undefined`)

в лоб это выглядит как-то совсем неуклюже :)

вариант 1:

```
if (value2 !== undefined)
    arr = [value2, ...arr];

if (value1 !== undefined)
    arr = [value1, ...arr];
```

вариант 2:

```
arr = (value2 !== undefined) ? [value2, ...arr] : arr;
arr = (value1 !== undefined) ? [value1, ...arr] : arr;
```

а есть ли какой-нибудь однострочный способ, типа

```
arr = [(value1 !== undefined) ? value1 : none, (value2 !== undefined) ? value2 : none, arr];
```

?

Comment: `arr = [value2, value1].filter(v => v !== undefined).concat(arr);`?

Comment: @wololo, неплохо!, но что делать, если `value` формируются так: `value2 = (stat) ? {x: 1, y: 2} : undefined`? Тогда в массив так просто значения не запихнуть

Comment: Можете пояснить подробнее, почему `value` просто так не поместить в массив?

Comment: можно, но получается немного извратно :) `arr = [a ? {x: 11} : {}, b ? {y: 12} : {}].filter(v => Object.keys(v).length !== 0).concat(arr);`

Comment: Ок, видимо я конкретно туплю :) Чему будет равен `arr` после выполнения представленного кода, и чем он отличается от результата, который вы бы хотели получить?

Comment: @wololo, если `a == undefined`, а `b != undefined`, то `arr = [{y: 12}, ...arr]`, что и хотелось бы получить и ваш код это делает, но в вашем коде (и моем вопросе) `value` сразу и ключ и значение, а если сравнение по 1 переменной, в добавление  массив другой - тут приходится использовать тернарный оператор сравнения, а если элементы массива - это объекты, то undefined уже как-то не проходят и надо передавать пустой объект (хотя тут не уверен - надо проверить) - проверил `arr = [a ? {x: 11} : undefined, {y: 12}].filter(v => v !== undefined).concat(arr);` работает :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Предполагаю, что все falsy значения кроме `undefined` допустимы. Если нет, можно упростить условия ниже).

Можно так:

```js
const array = ['foo'];

const a = 'bar';
const b = undefined;

array.unshift(
  ...(a !== undefined ? [a] : []),
  ...(b !== undefined ? [b] : []),
);

console.log(array);
```

Если нужно с перезаписью переменной, то так:

```js
let array = ['foo'];

const a = 'bar';
const b = undefined;

array = [
  ...(a !== undefined ? [a] : []),
  ...(b !== undefined ? [b] : []),
  ...array
];

console.log(array);
```

Comment: как вариант, правда если использовать typescript, то начинается ругань как раз из-за использования `[]`

Comment: А если заменить пустой массив на пустую строку? Это ведь тоже итератор, который распространяется в ноль аргументов.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let x = ['abc', 'qwert',]
let a;

x = !!a ? [a, ...x] : x
console.log(x)

a = 'sven'

x = !!a ? [a, ...x] : x
console.log(x)
```

Comment: как вариант, но на него начинает ругаться typescipt: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions`

Comment: реакт, что ли ?:) попробуй вместо пустых скобок `a = undefined` или `null`

Comment: он самый, но не сработало :(

Comment: переписал = попробуй ....в противном случае в eslint`е отключить эту проверку. Это как вариант 2 у тебя )

Comment: но ведь по сути это та самая запись `arr = (value2 !== undefined) ? [value2, ...arr] : arr;`, хотя подход с `!!` - то хорошо, хотя конечно бы хотелось в 1 строчку оба присваивания :)

Comment: такого способа не знаем-с ), чтобы в одну строку, да с проверкой двух переменных )